# Stretch height of div until the end of the page if there is margin-top

Tags: css, scroll, height, margin

I have the following code:

```
#content    {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -498px;
            margin-top: 186px;
            width: 984px;
            min-height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.875);
            font-size: 16px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index:2;
            padding-left: 8px;
            padding-right: 8px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
            padding-top: 8px;
            font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
            }
```

I took **min-height: 100%;** to make the div until the end, this works of course. But I also have a header picture and a menu so I wrote margin-top: 186px;
But now it will be stretched a little more than until the end (so I always have the possibility to scroll, even if it is not needed)

So basically the height of the div should be: 100% - 186px

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the calc property in css to do exactly what you wrote:

```
height: calc(100% - 186px);
```

This has great support in all modern browsers including IE9. As a fallback for IE8 (if you care about it at all), you can set the height first to 100%, then only the users with that browser will get the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your div with absolute position for that use below code

```
#content{
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;     
}
```